# Angular Warning Message Before Exiting a Page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I want a feature that gives a warning message when I try to; close the tab, exit the page or reload the page. The code I wrote for it is below. Right now, it gives a warning. Yet, it still exits the page before I can click “yes” or “no”. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div (window:beforeunload)="onWindowClose($event)"></div>
```

TS:

```
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onWindowClose(event: any): void {

 this.confirmDialogRef = this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: false,
});
this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
    "You will be exiting the page, are you sure?";

this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {});

  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Directive to achieve this

```js
@Directive({selector: 'button[counting]'})
class CountClicks {
  numberOfClicks = 0;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn) {
    console.log('button', btn, 'number of clicks:', this.numberOfClicks++);
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<button counting>Increment</button>',
})
class App {}
```

Comment: Especially on mobile, the beforeunload event is not reliably fired. For example, the beforeunload event is not fired at all in the following scenario:

A mobile user visits your page.
The user then switches to a different app.
Later, the user closes the browser from the app manager.
The beforeunload event is not compatible with the bfcache, because many pages using this event assume that the page will not continue to exist after the event is fired. To combat this, browsers will not place pages in the bfcache if they have beforeunload listeners, and this is bad for performance.